# setting a variable to get return from call back function using promise

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I am getting the "object" value instead of the exact value.
How do I get the value returned using a callback function?

```
function loadDB(option, callBack){
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred(),
        db = window.openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 1024*1024),
        selectQuery = "SELECT log FROM LOGS WHERE id = ?";
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(selectQuery,[option],function(tx,results){
            var retval;
            if( results.rows.length ) {
                retval = unescape(results.rows.item(0)['log']);
            }
            var returnValue = dfd.resolve(retval);
        });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
results = loadDB(2).then(function(val){ return val; } );
console.log("response***",results);
```

Answer (score 43):

A promise is like a closed box:

[image]

Your above code with the deferred object, creates the box, and lets you know that some time in the future you can open it. That time is when that above code will call `.resolve`.

When you do `results  = loadDB(2)` you are putting *a box* in results.

A promise also has a method that opens the box, works on the value and returns another box on the value (also opening any additional boxes along the way). That method is `.then`:

In boxes, it does:

[image] =>( [image: open]. => [image: e]) => [image: e]

That is, it takes the box, opens it and applies a function that does something to the value in it and then returns another box with the new value on it.

So, if you want to process the value, you need to hook on the one place where the box is open, like Bergi suggested:

```
loadDB(2).then(function(val){
    console.log("response***", val);
}); // this also returns a promise btw
```

Comment: Actually the function that gets applied does not need to open the box itself, it gets presented the value alone.

Comment: That's what the above notation says? It's like a monad in that sense - it takes a box (the this) and a function that takes an open box and returns a closed box - and returns a closed box on the second value - more formally (disregarding recursive assimilation) (M t)→(t→M u)→(M u) @Bergi

Comment: Yup, but the sentence below the image doesn't :-) Also, I'd rather make it "content of the box" instead of "open box", that would sound like `M t -> (OpenM t -> M u) -> M u`

Comment: Ah, then the images are ambiguous - the open box was supposed to represent the value itself being accessible. :)

Comment: Can this also be accomplished by doing `console.log(await loadDB(2))` and is it practicable?

Comment: @Brentspine yes

Answer (score 8):

You cannot get the resolve value *out* of a promise (here: asynchronous) context.

Instead, you will need to move the `console.log` call and everything else that depends on it *into* the promise context:

```
loadDB(2).then(function(val){
    console.log("response***", val);
});
```

Comment: @dystroy it's "how does asynchronous concurrency work in JavaScript" - these questions are common and they'll stay common. It's a fair question and Bergi's answer is good :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum of course it's a good answer. I just wonder if we should or not link to the big canonical QA.