# Return AJAX promise's result with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value, promise

Can someone explain why in the following example, foo() is returning the whole promise instead of just the data ? And how to make foo() return only the data ?

```
var foo = function() {
  var promise = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com'
  })

  return promise.done(function(data) {
    return data
  })
}

console.log(foo())
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well... You **do** return the promise explicitly. Please see the linked QA, as learning how to use the response on an asynchronous call  is a **very** frequent question.

Comment: You would be fine if you remove the return before the promise.xxx

Comment: @LShetty No, the log still wouldn't work

Comment: @LShetty also, it doesn't change the promise at all. `.done` in jQuery - unlike promise libraries like Q or Bluebird - returns the original promise.

Comment: `foo().then(function(data){ console.log(data); })` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Also related - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536385/setting-a-variable-to-get-return-from-call-back-function-using-promise/22536838#22536838 on what it logs.

Comment: There is no escape from asynchronous programming!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum with your solution, data is stuck inside a function. So if I need to manipulate it I have to do it inside then, not exactly what I need.

Comment: @inwpitrust read the comment just before yours. And also the linked *How to return the response from an AJAX call?* question. You can't do anything in JavaScript without learning event/asynchronous programming.

Comment: @dystroy yeah I upvoted that ;) And yes, I should have clarify my question with "Can JavaScript do that?".

Comment: @inwpitrust - yes, you have to put your code inside that function or chain it with .then

Answer (score 6):

Done always returns the promise, it does not make sense to return anything from the function that you supply to done:

> The deferred.done() method accepts one or more arguments, all of which
>   can be either a single function or an array of functions. When the
>   Deferred is resolved, the doneCallbacks are called. Callbacks are
>   executed in the order they were added. Since deferred.done() returns
>   the deferred object, other methods of the deferred object can be
>   chained to this one, including additional .done() methods
>   Source: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

`promise.done(...).done(...)` or `promise.done(fn1, fn2)` are equivalent.

You can use [.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) if you want to return a new promise with a new value for "data", i.e.:

```
promise.then(function(data1){
  return data1.result;
}).done(function(data2){
  //the value of data2 here will be data1.result 
});
```

A somewhat common use of then is to return a new promise, for example:

```
promise.then(function(data){
  return $.ajax(...);
}).done(function(resultFromAjaxCall){});
```

Comment: Yes, I get that, but I still don't understand why "it does not make sense to return anything from the function that you supply to done"?
See my response to BenjaminGruenbaum, what if I need to manipulate the data outside the promise "context"?

Comment: @inwpitrust It does not make sense simply because that value is not used (it is used in .then though). Also, you can update a variable outside of the scope of the promise's "context", making the data available outside the scope of the function that you pass to done.

Comment: "you can update a variable outside of the scope ..." that you can't do, the variable will always be undefined, see [this question's example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @inwpitrust It will be updated when the callback runs, if you check it immediately before it will be undefined or have the value it had previously. The behavior you're describing is to treat an async call as if it were synchronous.