# This method always returned an undefined value

Tags: angular, angular-services

The service actually get a right value from server (e.g. 1 or 0), but always returned an undefined value when I implemented the service in component. I think the `return` statement had just compiled before the `.then()` compiled. How can I fix this issue?

```
private isDuplicateNik(nik: number): boolean{
    let count: number;
    this.employeeService.isDuplicateNik(nik).then(
        res => {
            count = res;
        }
    );

    return (count > 0 ? false : true);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return value after a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951208/return-value-after-a-promise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
private isDuplicateNik(nik: number): Promise<boolean>{
    return this.employeeService.isDuplicateNik(nik).then(res => res < 0 ? false : true );
}
```

And even simpler:

```
private isDuplicateNik(nik: number): Promise<boolean>{
    return this.employeeService.isDuplicateNik(nik).then(res => res > 0);
}
```

You then use it like:

```
this.isDuplicateNik(...).then(res => {
    console.log("Res: ", res);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get an undefined input

Comment: also returned an error 'Type Promise<void> is not assignable  to type boolean', so I've to remove `: boolean`

Comment: I've updated the answer (type mismatch). Are you sure this.employeeService.isDuplicateNik(nik) returns a promise ? Try to log what you get when calling it, by doing:
this.employeeService.isDuplicateNik(nik).then(res => console.log(res));

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined input" ?

Comment: Yes, it returns a right value.
oh sorry, I mean undefined value. It shows 'undefined' in the console.

Answer (score 0):

since employeeService is an async function. count will be undefined when you return it.

```
private isDuplicateNik(nik: number) {
    let subject = Subject();
    this.employeeService.isDuplicateNik(nik).then(
        res => {
            subject.next(res > 0 ? false : true);
        }
    );

    return subject;
}
```

use as:

```
this.isDuplicateNik.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: returned errors 'Generic type Subject<T> required 1 type argument', and 'Type Promise<void> is not assignable to type boolean'

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see that you gave the function a return type. Just remove that.